# iOS - Interface responsive design, Unknown table cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been designing a custom table cell layout for my app (with auto layout) and I'm facing few problems.

This is how my custom table cell xib:

**My table cell XIB**

[image]

**What I cant find how to do:**

1. **The ImageView:** The images in these cells are from remote URLS (with JSON). **Their height and width is always different** and I don't know them. My goal is to make the width of the image always all over the screen width with few pixels margin from the device's screen (similar to Instagram image width) with the **scaled image's height** (proportional to the image's width).

**Instagram screenshot example**

[image]

2. Since I have no idea what the height of the image will be, how I can design the app so **the label will always below the image** with no much spacing? I mean - No matter where the images bottom is, the label will be always 10px under it.
3. I don't know the label length - so the next cell will have to start as soon as the label text ends. How do I accomplish that?

Hope to get some help with those things, I feel very frustrated about it since I've done this in one line of code in my Anroid version (whoever familiar with this - TopOf **anotherid** / BottomOf **anotherid**)

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayout can accomplish this for you - simply control-drag from your image to your label, and choose 'Vertical Spacing'. You'll want to use AutoLayout on the rest of your views to lay them out as well. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1).

Comment: Cool, Good to know. but now, for some reasons, my ImageView is over the text and I can't see the text. I think the next cell starts before the other one ends.. /:

Comment: You might need to look into setting a custom cell height programatically. Also, make sure that the label has a constrain to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: I have no idea how to get the height of a json string.. the height is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to define all constraints in you xib.

ImageView Leading & Trailing with superview. Top with something else. Bottom to the label. (I will not discuss label height handling here)
You have also to set a constraint for the ImageView height, let's say (100), then define this constraint as IBOutlet in your view controller.

2) once you got your image from internet, you have the SIZE. You then have to calculate the ratio (image.size.height / image.size.width)

3) get your ImageView 'width' and multiplies for the ratio, then set this new value (height) to the ImageView height constraint you have defined as IBOutlet

4) reload your indexpaths